# How to hide a text and replace it by another text

Tags: css

I have this div

```
        <div style="
          background-color: red;
          color: white;
          padding: 20px;
          border: 1px solid blue;
          font-size: 80px;">
            Hello Div
        </div>
```

`
and I want to hide "Hello Div" and replace it by "Osama"

I want to Know How I can do that.